# JSON returned undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I just try to get news data from googlenews, Here is the code;

```js
var myrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myrequest.open('GET', 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=00d8704f1a824d088a605d0ca...de1a16');
myrequest.onload = function() {
  var mydata = JSON.parse(myrequest.responseType);
  console.log(mydata[3]);
};
myrequest.send();
```

But when i check my logs it returns undefined. Is there anything wrong with my json parse ? Thanks for help!

Comment: You probably should change your API key, now that you just told it to everyone.

Comment: You probably want `responseText`, not `responseType`.  Also, the JSON you are getting back is an *object*, it does not have a key named `3`.

Answer (score 3):

There's two issues here. Firstly you need to parse `responseText`, not `responseType` - hence your error. Secondly, `mydata` will be an object so you can't access it by index. Presumably, this should be `mydata.articles[3]` instead. Try this:

```js
var myrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myrequest.open('GET', 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=00d8704f1a824d088a605d0ca4de1a16');
myrequest.onload = function() {
  var mydata = JSON.parse(myrequest.responseText);
  console.log(mydata.articles[3]);
};
myrequest.send();
```